# Sketch: How to cut a piece of a text that has been converted to outlines

Tags: sketch-app

From a letter "m" that was converted to outlines, I would like to cut it in the middle and then take the right piece, duplicate it, flip it horizontally and merge it with the first one.

In other words I want to take the second arch of the m and duplicate it in place of the first arch.

I haven't succeeded in cutting it correctly.

Comment: Hello 3371862 and welcome to GraphicDesign! What went wrong when you were trying to cut the m? We require more information about your attempts in order to help with implementation

Comment: Hello Zach, I was not using the correct tool: was using mask instead of substract. I've found the solution, see below. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well my question was trivial actually...

Here is a way:

- Draw a rectangle above the letter, position it as needed
- Select the letter (converted to outlines) and the rectangle and use the
  "substract" action: you get the desired part of the letter (i.e. the
  second "m" arch alone)
- Duplicate and flip horizontally
- Position it close to the first one